# Saving time when re-purposing a PC with a Bitlocker-encrypted HDD?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I understand that if you un-encrypt the drive of its Bitlocker, the bare filesystem can be zeroed out or securely wiped.

Wouldn't it be just as secure to securely x-pass wipe/write-with-zeros the file system in a pre-Windows boot environment without having to spend time decrypyting it?

Comment: Or, not decrypting the hard drive and just letting Windows setup delete that container partition to re-do a new Windows installation. Sure, that encrypted partition could be 'recoverable' but you'd just get it in an unusable encrypted chunk, right?

Comment: “I understand that if you un-encrypt the drive of its Bitlocker, the bare filesystem can be zeroed out or securely wiped.” - What?  This doesn’t make sense.

Comment: I was just rambling that if I unencrypt the drive, a simple format will just wipe the "TOC" of the file system and file recovery can still be done. I'd have to securely wipe with a couple passes of zeroes or other DBAN type methods.

Comment: Recovery of an encrypted file system.  Without a means to decrypt the file system recovery of the data would be pointless.  DBAN is overweighted.

Comment: Encrypted data is effectively meaningless if you don't have the decryption key. You aren't throwing away the Table of Contents to a book, you're burning the only dictionary to an alien language. You're making too many wrong assumptions, and you should stop doing that, and get back to the basic facts.

Answer (score 1):

Un-encrypting and already-encrypted partition re-writes all the data in decrypted form. This takes time, and then would require a full secure format to actually erase the data.

If you're balancing speed and security, then leave the original partition encrypted, and just delete the recovery keys or reset the TPM or configure your new computer image to not reuse an existing encrypted state and force a new encryption, new keys, all that.

The fact that the old data is encrypted, and you've removed/deleted the recovery keys, makes that old data unrecoverable and easily overwritten.

**UPDATE** ATA Secure Erase

NIST-approved deletion protocols for SSDs are met with the ATA Secure Erase standard, required to be implemented in any ATA drives (most desktop SSDs).

Using HDPARM this is a single command that can take between minutes and hours to complete according to documentation at kernel.org.

However, if you are simply prepping the drive for further use and want to securely erase previous data, the previous recommendations to forget the previous encryption keys and create new encrypted partitions is more than sufficient.